# Is Line secure?

Tags: cryptography, instant-messaging

I heard that Line social network store all the messages in their servers, but there exist another social networks that doesn't store any messages in any server. Are the servers that store all our messages secure?

Comment: Nobody will be able to answer this as its a relative question. It depends on how well they protect their information and what you consider secure.

Comment: it's easier for an adversary to get messages from a server that has them